# How to efficiently use a dictionary and a list of keys to find a list of values

Tags: python, pandas, search, data-structures

For example, I have a pandas data frame `df` like this:

```
    A  B
0  12  ['key1', 'key2']
1  23  ['key3', 'key4']
```

and I have a dictionary `dic` like this:

```
{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3'}
```

and I want to generate a column `df['C']` such that every element in the list in it are the values corresponding with the key in the lists of `df['B']`:

```
    A  B                 C
0  12  ['key1', 'key2']  ['value1', 'value2']
1  23  ['key3', 'key4']  ['value3', nan]
```

How can I achieve this in a time efficient manner? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use function

```
def check_dictionary(list_of_keys):
    return [dic[x] for x in list_of_keys if x in dic]
df['C']=df['B'].apply(check_dictionary)
```

Another approach is to use lambda:

```
df['C']=df['B'].apply(lambda row: [dic[key] for key in row if x in dic]
```

Comment: Thanks @ibadia! But how can it handle the case when `key4` is not found in `dict`?

Comment: you can put a condition in check_dictionary function. let me edit the code accordingly

Comment: edited the code for the key4 not found

Comment: Adding the condition `if x in dic` in the list comprehension doesn't appear to do exactly what the OP asked for. It just skips keys that are not found, rather than returning `nan` as in the question. Something like `return [dic.get(x, nan) for x in list_of_keys]` would be more faithful to the question.